# Does disabling depth test in Vulkan also disable depth write?

Tags: vulkan

The source of doubt in regard to this is that in OpenGL if you disable depth depth it also disables depth write. However I thought in Vulkan it doesn't (They are separate):

```
VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo::depthWriteEnable;
VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo::depthTestEnable;
```

I just want to confirm this as I can't find it in the docs that disabling one disables the other, I think they are separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depth write can *only* be enabled, when depth test is also enabled. If depth test is *disabled* then depth writes are *also* disabled, regardless of the value of `VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo::depthWriteEnable`.

See: https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo.html#_members

> depthWriteEnable controls whether depth writes are enabled when depthTestEnable is VK_TRUE. **Depth writes are always disabled when depthTestEnable is VK_FALSE**.